# Position fixed with height based on the content

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple modal with this CSS code

```
.modal {  
  max-width: 700px;
  position: fixed;  
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
  color: #eee;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 5%;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;  
}
```

This is fully responsive but I want use `bottom: auto` instead of `bottom: 5%`
Because that way if I don't have a lot of content in it, the height will adjust based on the content.

**The problem is when I have lot of content in it, I can no longer scroll down.**

Answer (score 1):

Using the position:fixed style cannot adjust by content because position: fixed style is set in accordance to the window.

if you want scrolling you will need to address the element that you have inside your modal that contains the content. On the content container you can use the overflow-y: auto to make it scroll when more content is in the element.

```css
.modal {  
      max-width: 700px;
      position: fixed;  
      margin: auto;
      background: #000;
      color: #eee;
      top: 5%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      max-height: 80%;
      padding: 20px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;  
    }
```

```html
    <div class="modal">
      <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm already using overflow-y: auto; like in the code that I shared

Comment: You have to use it on an element inside the modal element.

Comment: The style you shared has a fixed position and cannot use overflow-y: auto.

Comment: I tried... Can you show a code example that works? that's the all point of this website.

Comment: this additional div that you added isn't doing anything different as if it was without it, if we're going with the bottom: 5%, you'll end up with the same result, my intention was not to have the modal full height if you have for example just few words in the modal. just like how it behaves when you use bottom: auto

Comment: It scrolls when there is more content. Did you run the script snippet?

Comment: Yes, but it's also scrolling in my example so your additional code is redundant. what we're trying to achieve is for long content it will scroll and for not long content (if you have let's say one line of text) the height should NOT be 5% from the bottom, I want it to be auto, in other words based on the content that you have in that modal, it will end there and not 5% from the bottom, just like how bootstrap did it.

Comment: OK, it is now doing as you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `max-height` property along with `bottom:auto` for this.

```css
.modal-container {
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
  color: #eee;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-overlay" id="modal-overlay"></div>
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-container-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut numquam iure sapiente! Itaque similique aliquam sed eveniet, voluptatum quia enim sit dignissimos animi, laborum nisi iure expedita ut obcaecati nemo. Ipsum sed et illo quisquam tenetur vitae
      eos iure inventore itaque. Neque eaque itaque officiis eum distinctio error qui laudantium at! Dicta dolores inventore hic sit repellat, neque quos facere. Blanditiis enim incidunt quo expedita consequuntur ipsam eveniet molestiae ratione vitae
      cupiditate esse, at nam magnam velit delectus architecto numquam totam cum, perferendis neque quasi sed libero ducimus. Culpa, reprehenderit. Debitis eius sequi, porro quidem explicabo illum quasi placeat atque quo! Rerum repellat ipsam adipisci
      perferendis iusto perspiciatis quasi hic quis qui, at modi odit in optio vero tempora dolorum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, velit perspiciatis. Fuga excepturi quia laborum ipsam, alias repellendus. Tempore
      nam ducimus, nulla recusandae nostrum quibusdam neque accusamus ipsum assumenda aspernatur! Neque quis rem iusto quibusdam? Voluptatem pariatur explicabo facere suscipit qui voluptates itaque. Provident dolor esse obcaecati consequuntur voluptatibus,
      quos id quisquam deleniti libero neque aut facere! Accusamus, similique dolores? Commodi quaerat assumenda architecto sequi corrupti adipisci tempore aspernatur, dolor totam nesciunt accusamus, in repellat facilis quis recusandae perferendis ipsam
      ipsa nulla vitae natus quam? Labore cum nobis eveniet repudiandae? Quo tenetur blanditiis accusamus labore qui dolor rerum dolorum debitis! Commodi modi magni officiis repellendus fugiat nulla, doloremque itaque blanditiis cum dolorem ipsam incidunt
      sunt, qui, repudiandae facilis! Quos, ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti saepe dolores earum debitis. Ipsam quidem, repellat laborum sunt voluptatum, quam praesentium sequi necessitatibus quae debitis ad!
      Placeat modi harum ab! Amet quos aliquam accusantium cum perspiciatis nisi debitis explicabo. Saepe maiores corrupti quisquam, tempore, veritatis animi odit magni dolor eveniet delectus quas exercitationem. Blanditiis, dicta aliquid. Doloremque
      suscipit magnam culpa. Aliquid architecto voluptatum nobis aspernatur sit! Quaerat adipisci officiis vitae ut minima officia quasi at maiores corporis nostrum dolores quisquam illo suscipit nam repellat aperiam tempore iusto, dolore magnam delectus.Lorem
      Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```